# Position absolute in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

My website looks good on all browsers but Internet explorer.All the elements that have position:absolute are messed up . I tried to add left:0px rule but that didn't fix it.How can i fix the problem ?

Thank you !

Link to my website : [Click Here](http://www.danadesign.it)

Comment: Please include all necessary code _in your question_.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `position:relative` on the "main" element to `position:absolute` did the trick.

Comment: Trying to jump into the deep dark hole that is IE is never ending, so I wouldn't get too caught up with it. The important thing to note is that IE handles certain things different from other browsers (often times positioning, margins, etc), so it is important to consistently test. You'll find that a lot of the 'fixes' are sort of hacky, but it's the price you pay when supporting IE.

Answer (score 0):

The default is position:static for the parent (main) and this causes children with position:absolute to be absolute to the page. Making position:relative for main causes the children to be absolute within the main. It seems likely the IE difference is because it just happens to look okay in other browsers. See [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for more info. This example works in internet explorer and most others.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer { position:relative; height:100px; border:1px solid black; }
.inner { position:absolute; bottom:0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=outer>
    <div class=inner>
        This is some text.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```